# Performance difference in pandas read_table vs. read_csv vs. from_csv vs. read_excel?

Tags: python, performance, csv, pandas, dataframe

I tend to import .csv files into pandas, but sometimes I may get data in other formats to make `DataFrame` objects.

Today, I just found out about `read_table` as a "generic" importer for other formats, and wondered if there were significant performance differences between the various methods in pandas for reading .csv files, e.g. `read_table`, `from_csv`, `read_excel`.

1. Do these other methods have better performance than `read_csv`?
2. Is `read_csv` much different than `from_csv` for creating a `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. `read_table` is `read_csv` with `sep=','` replaced by `sep='\t'`, they are two thin wrappers around the same function so the performance will be identical.  `read_excel` uses the `xlrd` package to read xls and xlsx files into a DataFrame, it doesn't handle csv files.
2. `from_csv` calls `read_table`, so no.

Answer (score 14):

I've found that CSV and tab-delimited text (.txt) are equivalent in read and write speed, both are much faster than reading and writing MS Excel files. However, Excel format compresses the file size a lot.

---

For the same 320 MB CSV file (16 MB .xlsx) 
(i7-7700k, SSD, running Anaconda Python 3.5.3, Pandas 0.19.2)

Using the standard convention `import pandas as pd`

2 seconds to read .csv `df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv')` (same for pd.read_table)

15.3 seconds to read .xlsx `df = pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx')`

10.5 seconds to write .csv `df.to_csv('bar.csv', index=False)`
(same for .txt)

34.5 seconds to write .xlsx `df.to_excel('bar.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)`

---

To write your dataframes to tab-delimited text files you can use:

`df.to_csv('bar.txt', sep='\t', index=False)`

Comment: FYI to others, `to_csv` has a `compression` argument so you can write out to a compressed file. See [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) docs. Not sure how well the compression here compare to Excel's format though.

Comment: nowadays in `df.to_csv` you can end your filename with `.gz` and pandas will gzip automatically.