# python pandas dataframe: naming columns is making new columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have csv data in a txt file like:

```
20050601,      25.22,      25.31,      24.71,      24.71,   27385
20050602,      24.68,      25.71,      24.68,      25.45,   16919
20050603,      25.07,      25.40,      24.72,      24.82,   12632
```

I want to put this data into a pandas dataframe with the columns named `date`,`close`,`high`,`low`,`open`,`volume`.

When I use this code:

```
df = pd.read_table(File,header=None,names=['date', 'close', 'high', low', 'open', 'volume'])
```

the output is:

```
                                             date  close  high  low  \
0     20050601,      25.22,      25.31,      24.71, ...    NaN   NaN  NaN   
1     20050602,      24.68,      25.71,      24.68, ...    NaN   NaN  NaN   
2     20050603,      25.07,      25.40,      24.72, ...    NaN   NaN  NaN   
  open  volume  
0      NaN     NaN  
1      NaN     NaN  
2      NaN     NaN  `
```

When I use:

```
df = pd.read_table(File,header=None)
```

the output is:

```
                                                      0
0     20050601,      25.22,      25.31,      24.71, ...
1     20050602,      24.68,      25.71,      24.68, ...
2     20050603,      25.07,      25.40,      24.72, ...
```

I think that zero in the header when header is set to none is over the far right column and is causing the new names to go to the right of it, creating new columns.  I'm not sure though.

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with separator `,\s+` to indicate a `,` and arbitrary whitespace:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""20050601,      25.22,      25.31,      24.71,      24.71,   27385
20050602,      24.68,      25.71,      24.68,      25.45,   16919
20050603,      25.07,      25.40,      24.72,      24.82,   12632"""


#after testing change io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep=",\s+", 
                 header=None, 
                 names=['date','close','high','low','open','volume'], 
                 engine='python')

print df

       date  close   high    low   open  volume
0  20050601  25.22  25.31  24.71  24.71   27385
1  20050602  24.68  25.71  24.68  25.45   16919
2  20050603  25.07  25.40  24.72  24.82   12632
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this:

```
df = pd.read_table(File,names=['date','close','high','low','open','volume'],sep=',' )
```

Anyone know why the `sep=','` makes it take 2 times longer?
[Performance difference in pandas read_table vs. read_csv vs. from_csv vs. read_excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362573/performance-difference-in-pandas-read-table-vs-read-csv-vs-from-csv-vs-read-e)

Comment: Because it is properly working and before it wasn't?

Comment: if your separator is `,` why not just read using `pd.read_csv`?