# OSError: Initializing from file failed

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a simple csv read for my code and it has worked up until I tried tonight for Mac. Currently on 10.15.3, Catalina. This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_table('/Users/nicholasmori/Desktop/FINAL.csv', delimiter=',')
```

And the error it gave me was:
OSError: Initializing from file failed.
Ive tried multiple different options to read this csv, including

```
pd.read.csv(open( ) )
csv.reader( )
pd.read_csv()
with open ( ) as csvfile:
```

But all these give similar errors. I am sure theres a simple answer, but I haven't been able to find it. Ive tried the
***sudo chown username:group filename***
command on terminal, and allowed terminal access through my privacy/firewall settings. My file also has Read & Write permissions for "everyone," unless I'm viewing that wrong. Does anyone have a solution for me?

Comment: Is this helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552404/oserror-initializing-from-file-failed-on-csv-in-pandas ?

Comment: Unless Im viewing this wrong, my file has both Read & Write Permissions for everyone. I looked at that earlier and don't think thats it.

Comment: Can you please share the error with read_csv()?  did you try with read_table() without the delimiter=','?
Actually, read_table() with delimiter=',' is the same as read_csv(). This link explains it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362573/performance-difference-in-pandas-read-table-vs-read-csv-vs-from-csv-vs-read-e#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=read_table%20is%20read_csv%20with%20sep,from_csv%20calls%20read_table%20%2C%20so%20no.

Comment: The same error occurs when I do read_csv(). "OSError: Initializing from file failed" And yes, I tried removing/adding the delimiters and other arguments to see what would happen

Comment: I’m pretty desperate to get this very minor part to work so if you have any suggestions at all I’m willing to try it!

Comment: Are you able to open the file with other software (excel or similar)?

Comment: @TomRon yes I am able to open it with Numbers (Mac equivalent software)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, what I did was upload the file to jupyter from my Mac (same root of the python program) and:

```
import pandas as pd

path_file = "FileName.csv" 
data = pd.read_csv(path_file)
```

Hope works!

Answer (score 0):

When did you upgrade from macOS Catalina (10.15.x) from a previous version (10.14)?  OS-level access rights are a bit different.

Also, you can try this, to verify that the file (and path, if provided) are correct:

```
from pathlib import Path
file_name = 'test.npy'
Path(file_name).is_file() # returns True or False
print(Path.cwd())         # prints current working directory
```